# Rest endpoint request code [200] produces an empty Json file?

Tags: json, gis, arcgis, arcpy

I am trying to query and ArcGIS rest endpoint and copy it's features to a locally hosted feature class. My request gives me code [200] indicating that it successfully retrieves the rest end point, but when I write my data to a json file there is no data.

Here is my request code:

```
#Get data from rest service 
params = {'where':'1=1','outFields':'*','f':'json','returnGeometry': True, 'geometryType':'esriGeometryPolygon'}
r = requests.get("url",params)
#Check results of get request 
print(r)
data = r.json()
#save JSON to disc 
with open("json file path",'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
#Copy json data to feature class
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion("json file path", "feature class")
```

This is the rest endpoint I am trying to download from: https://gis.cachecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/BaseMap/Parcels_Current/FeatureServer/query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are using is pointing the service, not the layer. Add the layer ID to the URL and your code should work.

For example:

https://gis.cachecounty.org/arcgis/rest/services/BaseMap/Parcels_Current/FeatureServer/0/query

Note the **/0/** before the `query` part, which points to the "Cache Parcels" layer.